# Finding a 90s mystery/haunted house game

Tags: identify-this-game

I’ve been trying to remember the name of a game I used to play as a kid that would have come out in the 90s. Unfortunately my memory is hazy but here are the details I remember:

- Portrait oriented board
- The art on the board was a mansion
- I want to say it was halloween or mystery themed
- You would navigate through the house, using things like trapdoors and such

I have seen these in my search and confirmed they aren’t it:

- Which Witch
- Haunted House
- Haunted Mansion
- Ghost Castle
- Clue
- Creepy Towers

Comment: Hi. Could you clarify what you mean by "portrait oriented board"?

Answer (score 4):

**Is this 13 DeadEnd Drive?**

The art is mansion based, the traps are interactive.

If my memory serves, I think the gameplay revolves around a group of party invitees squabbling over an inheritance. . .

[image: 1313 DeadEnd Drive board, set up and ready for play. Featuring mansion art and interactive plastic traps.]

[image: Box Art for 13 DeadEnd Drive]

Comment: Note that "13 dead-end drive" and "1313 dead-end drive" are actually slightly different games. Your first picture is "13 dead-end drive". "1313 dead-end drive" has more cartoony artwork, doesn't have the "portrait" mechanism, and instead has a character flowchart with flowing money.

Comment: Good catch. . . It looks like 1313 was a spinoff version. If the OP played it in the 90's, it's likely "13", not "1313".

Answer (score -1):

I am probably shooting far off mark here, but I had a similar quest not long ago, my memory wasn't 100% but same idea: game I played in the 90's -- 96' or so. I eventually found my goal: Goosebumps Terror in the graveyard board game by Milton Bradley.

https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/813/goosebumps-terror-graveyard-game

I know it's not to your specifications but I'm trying to be helpful in crossing off alternative possibilities.

Cheers.